# A way to start tomcat with other java

Tags: java, tomcat

I am exporting variables in the setenv.sh like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/arthur/java8
JRE_HOME=/home/arthur/java8/jre
CATALINA_HOME=/home/arthur/tomcat8
PATH=$CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

But tomcat started from tomcat8 folder starts with java6 variable. 
Why?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring tomcat configuration file using command

```
sudo vim /etc/default/tomcat7
```

## ...

> The home directory of the Java development kit (JDK). You need at
>   least  JDK version 1.5. If JAVA_HOME is not set, some common
>   directories for  OpenJDK, the Sun JDK, and various J2SE 1.5 versions
>   are tried.
>
> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-6-jdk
>
> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

## ...

Then restart the server

```
sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

You can use below command to check Tomcat is using which JDK

```
 sudo service tomcat7 status
```

Comment: sorry, what files I must edit with vim? And what changes are needed? And geidt is the same way, I think. setenv.sh was already edited.